# Find Average and Instantaneous Velocity of a Function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Use the following function, f(t)=3t^3+t, to find the average velocity of:

a. t=2 and t=0
b. t=2 and t=1
c. t=2 and t=1.9
d. t=2 and t=1.99
e. the instantaneous velocity at t=2

I have trouble with part e. The formula for instantaneous velocity is:

v(a)=(lim/x->x) (s(a+h)-s(a))/h

Do I write it out as v(a)= ((3(2+h)^3)+(2+h))-(3(2)^3+(2))/h?

Comment: What have you be given as the definition of the average velocity ?

Answer (score 0):

a) Average Velocity on [0, 2] = (f(2) - f(0))/(2 - 0) = 26/2 = 13 ft/sec.
Other cases are done similarly.

b) Instantaneous velocity at t = 2 is: f'(2) = 9*t^2 + 1 evaluated at t = 2 ==> f'(2) = 37 ft/sec.

Comment: The average velocity can have another defintion and the results for questions $a,b,c,d$ would differ.